# dataReceived event in .net compact 2.0 for Windows CE 6.0 only works once for serial comm

Tags: serial-port, compact-framework, windows-ce, c#-2.0

I have  simple serial port program that is supposed to read the serial port and echo back the characters typed.  I can get this to work fine by polling the serial recieved with a timer, but I'd like to use the dataReceived event instead.  For some reason the event will occur once but never again.

```
    SerialPort bsp;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bsp = new SerialPort("COM2", 2400, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        bsp.DataReceived +=new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(whasup);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        bsp.Open();
    }
    void whasup(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        char[] text = new char[100];
        int temp = bsp.BytesToRead;
        string j = temp.ToString();
        bsp.Read(text, 0, temp);
        bsp.Write(text, 0, temp);
    }
```

I've tried porting this to a PC and it works great, but on this Windows CE device it really doesn't want to cooperate.  I know the serial object is still open because i've had a timer running spitting text out of the Win CE device even after it stop echoing back its receive data.  I also had the timer output bsp.BytesToRead, and I could see that value climb as I typed more keys in on my PC that talked serially to the Windows CE device.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suffered similar problems with `Read()` but managed it with `ReadExisting()` instead, to always read the whole buffer.  It may be this fact that allows the next event to be raised.

The `Sleep(500)` was included because the event is raised as soon as the first byte is written to the buffer.  Through some trial/error and in the knowledge that the messages we were reading never exceeded a particular length, we knew they'd be fully written within (and in fact long before) 500ms of the event.

A bit hit/miss and I'd be more than happy to see a 'correct' solution from a serial expert!

The code:

```
private SerialPort port;
private object readLock = new object();

private SerialManager()
{
    port = new SerialPort(SerialPort, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
    port.Open();
}

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Lock to subsequent DataReceived events
    lock (readLock)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        string data = port.ReadExisting();
    }
}
```